# Ajax loading images after displaying data

Tags: html, css, ajax

I am using ajax to get data from a php file

```
function getdata(param)
{
var xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==1||xmlhttp.readyState==2||xmlhttp.readyState==3)
{

    document.getElementById('center_content').innerHTML="Loading....";
}
else if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{

document.getElementById('center_content').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","./includes/getd.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xmlhttp.send("content_getter="+param);
}
```

and the php file looks something like

```
if($_POST['content_getter']=='home')
{
echo<<<END
  <div id="background2">
<img src="images/cent.jpg" class="stretch2" alt="" />
</div> 
DATA DATA DATA DATA
END;
}
```

Now the problem is that the div center content shows loading... and after that it starts loading the image.I want the image to be loaded while the "Loading..." is being displayed and then image to be displayed in one go.

Comment: nope..if it serves the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you'r accepting jQuery based solutions, try something like that:

```
function getdata(param) {
    $('#center_content').html("Loading....");
    $.post("./includes/getd.php?content_getter=" + param, function(data){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            $('#center_content').html(data);
        };
        img.src = $(data).find("#background2 .strech2").attr('src');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first load the image in a hidden div and then copy the html (using jQuery) to your target div.

Comment: That won't be helpful as the file will be bulky defeating the whole purpose of loading content using AJAX